# Issue while scrubbing video using AVPlayer

Tags: ios, video, avplayer

I am reading video from local using AVPlayer. When I scrub through the video, sometimes I am getting pixelated video for few second or green screen appears for a while.

Following is my code for scrubbing:

```
 - (void)playerControlView:(PlayerControlView *)playerControlView beganScrubbingAtPercent:(float)timePercent
{
    if (_avPlayer.rate > 0) {
        _resumePlayAfterScrub = YES;
    } else {
        _resumePlayAfterScrub = NO;
    }
}

- (void)playerControlView:(PlayerControlView *)playerControlView scrubbedToPercent:(float)timePercent
{
    if (_avPlayer.rate > 0) {
        [_avPlayer pause];
        [_loadingView startAnimating];
    }

    float durationSeconds = CMTimeGetSeconds(_avPlayerItem.duration);
    CMTime cmTime = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(durationSeconds * timePercent, NSEC_PER_SEC);
    [_avPlayer seekToTime:cmTime toleranceBefore:kCMTimeZero toleranceAfter:kCMTimeZero];

    [_hideControlsTimer invalidate];
}

- (void)playerControlView:(PlayerControlView *)playerControlView finishedScrubbingAtPercent:(float)timePercent
{
    if (_resumePlayAfterScrub) {
        [_avPlayer play];
    }
    [self resetCurrentEventWithCopy:YES];
}
```

what can I optimize on above code?

Answer (score 0):

It could be a case wherein the gap between consecutive IDR frames is high so when you seek, it takes a while to hit the closest IDR frame and clear picture buffer. Till the player hits an IDR frame, it will not be able to decode the stream properly which will result in you seeing green screens and pixelations.